# How do I write the page contents of an html page into a php file?

Tags: php, html

I am wrote a php code which will login to a grade system using HTTP POST method, but I am having trouble writing the content of the page into a php file or any file in general.

```
 try {
    $curl = curl_init();
    $fP = fopen("assigmentcode.php","w");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $pagecontent = curl_exec($curl);

    fwrite($fP,$pagecontent);
        fclose($fP);
          header('Location: assigmentcode.php');

    curl_close($curl); 


   }
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: You are not capturing what is returned by CURL ... `$pagecontent = curl_exec($curl);`

Comment: @cmorrissey I updated my code, but the assignments.php is still zero bytes

Comment: Check your permissions on that file/folder. The web user needs write access.

Comment: How would I do that @webomatik

Comment: @Webomatik http://puu.sh/oVMq1/5b5f1bbfc1.png, and the file is still zero bytes.

Comment: What OS are you working with?

Comment: I am working with mac osx, el capitan